# Optimise while loop nested in an IF condition

Tags: python, mergesort

What I'm trying to accomplish is: **given two lists sorted in increasing order, create and return a merged list of all the elements in sorted order (merge-sort)**.

The code I have written is:

```py
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    a = 0
    for it2 in list2:
        if a < len(list1):
            while it2 > list1[a]:
                a += 1
                if a == len(list1):
                    break

        list1.insert(a, it2)
        a += 1
    return(list1)
```

I was inititally using the following while condition by combining it with the preceding IF:

```
while it2 > list1[a] and a < len(list1):
```

But that kept giving me the following error for `list1 = ['aa', 'xx', 'zz']`, `list2 = ['bb', 'cc']`

> File "/Users/zainkhaishagi
>   1/Downloads/google-python-exercises/basic/list2.py", line 35, in
>   linear_merge
>       while it2 > list1[a] and a < len(list1): IndexError: list index out of range

Upon debugging it seems that the even though the while-condition has an AND in it which is false, the index being passed into `list1` is out of range. I was hoping that the false AND condition would make the while condition a false without checking for index of `list1`. Apparently, that is not the case.

1. Am I missing something here since AND is supposed to be False even if a single input is False ?
2. Is there any way to optimise this code further using the same approach as I've used? (The constraints I gave myself were to not create a new list and not use more than one variable and to iterate the least number of times on the lists)

Comment: Test the index before trying to use it: `while a < len(list1) and it2 > list1[a]:`

Comment: Post the script that's having the problem, not the script that works. It's hard to tell what you're talking about when you just describe how you changed it.

Comment: If this is simply a programming exercise then great, otherwise itertools is your friend:  `filter(None, chain(*izip_longest(list1, list2)))`

Comment: Ok so you're trying to a merge sort of `list1, list2` of integers. One tip about keeping variable names obvious: use `x1,x2` or `e1,e2` or `v1,v2` for the element/value names (not `it2`), and `i2` for the walking index into list2, not `a`. Also, add some print statements for all the relevant values to help you debug your own code.

Comment: Also, define what 'optimize my code' means: fewer lines of code, clearer code (rename your variables, already!), better big-O performance in the typical case, or some compromises of all of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of what you had initially from:

```py
while it2 > list1[a] and a < len(list1)
```

to:

```py
while a < len(list1) and it2 > list1[a]
```

If the first condition is not `True` it won't be evaluated any further. Have a look at this example without the additional `if`:

```py
def linear_merge(list1, list2):
    a = 0
    for it2 in list2:
        while a < len(list1) and it2 > list1[a]:
            a += 1
            if a == len(list1):
                break

        list1.insert(a, it2)
        a += 1
    return list1
```

I hope that helps!